# Count of Saturdays and Sundays in a given month in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

How can I get a count of the Saturdays and the Sundays in a given month  in PostgreSQL?

I am getting total days count, or total Saturday and Sunday days in a month.

For month days code:

```
SELECT DATE_PART ('days', DATE_TRUNC('month', NOW()) 
+ '1 MONTH'::INTERVAL - '1 DAY'::INTERVAL);
```

If the month has 30 days, but I want the 22 days count (remove the weekend count) or total Saturday and Sunday days in a month.

Comment: Just a note that 9.4 is out of support - you should upgrade as soon as possible and all versions of 9 will be [out of support/EOL by](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) from Nov 11th next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use `generate_series()` to get a set of all days of the month and then filter it with a `WHERE` clause checking the weekday for every day.

```
SELECT count(*)
  FROM generate_series(date_trunc('month', now()),
                       date_trunc('month', 
                                   now()) + '1 month'::interval - '1 day'::interval,
                                  '1 day'::interval) gs(d)
  WHERE extract(DOW FROM gs.d) IN (6,0);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=7d423e758d096085d3df7fe557d2bc93)

Comment: other options are to use count with a filter or a case expression

Comment: thank you @sticky bit